# Linking error at tessellation shaders in GLSL

Tags: opengl, glsl, c, tessellation

I'm testing the triangle tessellation from the link http://prideout.net/blog/?p=48#shaders . All the shader are compiled correctly, but when I try to link the program using the command:

```
glLinkProgram(programID);
```

I got the following error:

```
Tessellation control info
(0): error C6029: No input primitive type
----------------------------------------
Tessellation evaluation info
(0): error c7005: No tessellation primitive mode specified
-----------------------------------------------------------
Geometry info
(0): error C6022: No input primitive type
(0): error C6029: No ouput primitive type
----------------------------------------
Not valid
```

It's so strange I declare output for TC Shader using command:

```
layout(vertices = 3) out;
```

And input layout for TE shader using command:

```
layout(triangles, equal_spacing, cw) in;
```

Why I still got this error?
I hope to see you answer about it.

I put my shaders in below:

Vertex shader:

```
#version 410 core

in vec4 Position;
out vec3 vPosition;

void main()
{
    vPosition = Position.xyz;
}
```

TC shader:

```
#version 410 core

layout(vertices = 3) out;
in vec3 vPosition[];
out vec3 tcPosition[];

#define ID gl_InvocationID

void main()
{
    float TessLevelInner = 3;
    float TessLevelOuter = 2; 
    tcPosition[ID] = vPosition[ID];
    if (ID == 0) {
        gl_TessLevelInner[0] = TessLevelInner;
        gl_TessLevelOuter[0] = TessLevelOuter;
        gl_TessLevelOuter[1] = TessLevelOuter;
        gl_TessLevelOuter[2] = TessLevelOuter;
    }
}
```

TE Shader:

```
#version 410 core
//TessEval

layout(triangles, equal_spacing, cw) in;
in vec3 tcPosition[];
out vec3 tePosition;
out vec3 tePatchDistance;
uniform mat4 Projection;
uniform mat4 Modelview; 

void main()
{
    vec3 p0 = gl_TessCoord.x * tcPosition[0];
    vec3 p1 = gl_TessCoord.y * tcPosition[1];
    vec3 p2 = gl_TessCoord.z * tcPosition[2];
    tePatchDistance = gl_TessCoord;
    tePosition = normalize(p0 + p1 + p2);
    gl_Position = Projection * Modelview * vec4(tePosition, 1);
}
```

Geometry shader:

```
#version 410 core
//geometry shader
layout(triangles) in;
layout(triangle_strip, max_vertices = 3) out;
in vec3 tePosition[3];
in vec3 tePatchDistance[3];
out vec3 gFacetNormal;
out vec3 gPatchDistance;
out vec3 gTriDistance;
uniform mat4 Modelview;
uniform mat3 NormalMatrix;

void main()
{
    vec3 A = tePosition[2] - tePosition[0];
    vec3 B = tePosition[1] - tePosition[0];
    gFacetNormal = NormalMatrix * normalize(cross(A, B));

    gPatchDistance = tePatchDistance[0];
    gTriDistance = vec3(1, 0, 0);
    gl_Position = gl_in[0].gl_Position; EmitVertex();

    gPatchDistance = tePatchDistance[1];
    gTriDistance = vec3(0, 1, 0);
    gl_Position = gl_in[1].gl_Position; EmitVertex();

    gPatchDistance = tePatchDistance[2];
    gTriDistance = vec3(0, 0, 1);
    gl_Position = gl_in[2].gl_Position; EmitVertex();

    EndPrimitive();
}
```

Fragment Shader:

```
#version 410 core
//fragment shader
out vec4 FragColor;
in vec3 gFacetNormal;
in vec3 gTriDistance;
in vec3 gPatchDistance;
in float gPrimitive;
uniform vec3 LightPosition;

float amplify(float d, float scale, float offset)
{
    d = scale * d + offset;
    d = clamp(d, 0, 1);
    d = 1 - exp2(-2*d*d);
    return d;
}

void main()
{
    vec3 AmbientMaterial = vec3(0.04f, 0.04f, 0.04f);
    vec3 DiffuseMaterial = vec3(0, 0.75, 0.75);
vec3 LightPosition = vec3(0.25, 0.25, 1);
    vec3 N = normalize(gFacetNormal);
    vec3 L = LightPosition;
    float df = abs(dot(N, L));
    vec3 color = AmbientMaterial + df * DiffuseMaterial;

    float d1 = min(min(gTriDistance.x, gTriDistance.y), gTriDistance.z);
    float d2 = min(min(gPatchDistance.x, gPatchDistance.y), gPatchDistance.z);
    color = amplify(d1, 40, -0.5) * amplify(d2, 60, -0.5) * color;

    FragColor = vec4(color, 1.0);
}
```

Comment: are you sure you are initializing OpenGL 4.0 context ?

Comment: hi concept3d, :), thanks for your support. I use const char* version = (const char*)glGetString(GL_VERSION); and the result is "OpenGL 4.4".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem. The error is in the code of loading shader.

```
glShaderSource(pShader[st], 1, (const GLchar**)sProgram, NULL);
```

I changed 1 to size of the char* array sProgram